# Wordpress site went down after deleting a plugin via ftp

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I wanted to update the Revolution Slider plugin so I just went in via FTP, deleted the folder and added the new plugin folder. When I went to the site I got a very basic 500 error with not much info (in Chrome).

I tried removing the plugin, replacing it with the original, removing the htaccess file, putting in a blank htaccess file but nothing seems to bring the site back up.

I now have the original revolution slider plugin installed and the htaccess file with the rewrite rules (basically as it was when the site was working last).

I am at a loss for what to do next. Any suggestions? Here is the site location:

http://innerwestadv.com/damonte/

Comment: I also tried increasing the memory limit through a php.ini file.

Comment: The main site on that server works... http://innerwestadv.com/

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to go into the database and deactivate all of the plugins.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-deactivate-all-plugins-when-not-able-to-access-wp-admin/